# java logger calling from another class

Tags: java, logging

I'm learning this logger from java and trying to call the class MyLogger from the main class but it seems not to be working

MyLogger.java

```
public class MyLogger {

    public MyLogger() {

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
        FileHandler fh;
        try {

        fh = new FileHandler("c:\\opt\\MyLogFile.log", true);
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,"My first log");

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
public class Client {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
        LOGGER.getName();
        LOGGER.getClass();
        LOGGER.info("ABC");


    }
}
```

1. Why is it not calling the MyLogger.java to create the log file?
2. Is there a beter way to log the eclipse console rather than putting LOGGER on each methods for each class?
3. Why some uses flush() before closing the log file?

Comment: Why do you think it should use your `MyLogger`?

Comment: where in the Client.java does it even mention MyLogger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it not calling the MyLogger.java to create the log file?

If *it* refers to running `Client`, then that's because there is no relation between that class and your `MyLogger` class.

> Is there a beter way to log the eclipse console rather than putting
>   LOGGER on each methods for each class?

*Better* is very subjective. The majority of source code I've seen use the paradigm you're using in your `Client` class. That is, declaring a `static final Logger` with the name of enclosing class and using it where you need to log something within that class.

Some applications make use of AOP concepts for logging.

> Why some uses flush() before closing the log file?

Some implementations may buffer log messages so as not to make many small IO system calls, but instead make few big ones. Closing the log file may not flush the buffer, so you'll want to `flush` it explicitly.